# Querying with conditions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Assume, we have two tables: "Items" and "Types". The relationships are:

```
item belongs_to type
type has_many items
```

Also, the Item table have a column, let's call it "mark". What would be a query (in a Rails secure way if it's possible) to extract all the types from them Types table, which have connected items in Items table with a "mark"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
Type.find :all, :include => items, :conditions => ['items.mark = ?', somevalue]
```

should work.

Note: you shouldn't use `Type` as class name, nor `:type` as attribute, as this name can lead to conflicts.

Comment: Thanks! You unclosed :include for me! The Type-like names were for example only